# Hiding text upon loading a page

Tags: html, typescript

I am trying to hide a div on page load. Whenever the page loads, I want certain text to appear or disappear depending on the result of an API call.

Forgive the noob question, I am new to TypeScript and Vue in general.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    <div class="row" v-if="!isHidden">
      <p>
        Your file is available!
      </p>
    </div>
```

While my TypeScript looks like this:

```
@Component
export default class File extends Vue {

  @Prop()
  private isHidden: boolean;

  private async init(): Promise<void> {
    this.File = [];
    this.isHidden = true;

    this.File = await API.file.downloadFile(
    );
  
    if (this.File !== ['']) {
      this.isHidden = false;
    }
```

The above TypeScript calls the API on page load. What do I do for the text to appear whenever `this.File` does not return an empty `String[]`?

Comment: `this.File.lenght > 0`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @AmanSharma

Comment: when the `this.File` have array in it, it means its length increased by 0. only then you can show your text

Comment: @AmanSharma thanks for the suggestion! However it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new attribute in the data section of your vue component or in your state if you are using vuex.

When you call the api, set the new attribute to 'loading'. When the api returns data, if is valid data, set your attribute to 'valid', if is invalid, set to 'invalid'. You can use other strings for others cases. Then, you can change your message depends on the string you have in the attribute, or hidden the data if you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My apologies, but I cannot visualize what you just said. Can you share an example?

Comment: Check how data works in vue components, add a data to your component if you dont have, and add the attribute to data. When you call the api, set the attribute to 'loading', so you can hide the section or show and message like 'loading data' or similar. When the api responds, check the response, and change the attribute of you have to anything you need.

Comment: @johnnyrocket33 He means something like this: `data: { text: "stuff that gets changed" , status: "loaded" }, methods: { loadFromApi() { this.status = "loading"; } }`. Whenever your loading of the Data is done, change the status back to "loaded" or something along the lines. Then you make a v-show on your div that you want to hide. e.g.: `<div v-show="status === 'loaded'">`

Comment: Exactly, thanks @D.Schaller, but with v-if instead of v-show.

Comment: @MRMarkII You're welcome

Comment: Will try to put it in TypeScript. Thanks for that again!